# Basic xslt: Hiding slots created from custom xslt

Tags: development, xslt, content-query-web-part

I've followed and managed to successfully implement this:

http://www.entwicklungsgedanken.de/2008/05/18/add-the-icon-of-the-file-type-to-a-custom-xsl-template-when-using-the-contentbyquerywebpart-cqwp/

As I'm including the relevant fields and evaluating them like `string(@HTML_x005F_x0020_File_x005F_x0020_Type)`, for example, it's creating them as slots and exposing these on the 'Edit Web Part' panel - but they are not to be displayed there - they have no purpose there. Can anybody please guide me in the right direction of hiding them from the UI?

Comment: I've already asked in your other question (but you have not reacted): What is a slot?

Answer (score -2):

please you don't have a image? I think that you can use JQuery +  CSS to hide the elements, but i'm not sure because i don't understant very well.